# how to execute the step one by one during call?

Tags: java, android

i want to execute each number and give time delay for every step.
the first number is a conference number and second is a time delay.
when user press the sample it should execute the steps one by one according to delay

![Conference steps][10]

Comment: What´s your question? `Uri.parse()` or making a delay? And what problem do you want us to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Time delay can be simply implemented by using Thread.sleep() method
Ex: Thread.sleep(1000); will call implicit wait for 1 sec.

Answer (score 0):

- Use [timerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html) and write your code in `run ()` method
- use delay as per your requirement
- make one `counter` which increment after every timer executed
- when counter exceed your limit  (`profile.getSteps()` ) then cancel that timer .

Comment: do you have any sample program